# Level sets of distance to closest gaussian integers for complex valued functions.

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Say we have complex valued function $$z \to f(z) \text{ such that } \cases{z\phantom{(f)}\in\mathbb{C} \\f(z) \in \mathbb{C}}$$
We now want to investigate:
$$|f(z) - \text{round}(f(z))|$$

Where **round** is the *closest Gaussian integer*, i.e. the $w$ which fulfills $$\text{round}(f(z)) = w \text{ such that } \cases{\min_w\{|f(z)-w|\}\\ w=a+bi \\ a,b\in \mathbb{Z}} $$

And we want to measure the level sets of the grid when we plot these functions:

**Below:** Example of depiction of $f(z) = z$.
[image]
**Below:** Example where $f(z) = z^2$
[image]

We see that if we follow the largest distance to round we do get grids which are curved or twisted. How can we calculate the paths of that grid? Can we express it in terms of $f(z)$?

---

**Hint** thanks to Martin R in the comments; maybe the [pre-image or inverse image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Inverse_image) has something to do with it..?

Comment: Aren't that just the pre-images of the horizontal lines $\operatorname{Re} w = k + 0.5$ and the vertical lines $\operatorname{Im} w = k + 0.5$ for all integers $k$?

Comment: (Exchange "horizontal" and "vertical" in my last comment.)